# Wo er nur bleibt

Tags: word-usage, modal-particle

*Frankie unsichtbar* (book by Zoran Drvenkar and Martin Baltscheit):

> Als Frankie wieder wach wird, ist es schon dunkel. Er bekommt jetzt doch ein wenig Angst. Es ist spät, seine Mutter und seine Oma werden sich fragen, wo er *nur* bleibt.

Could *nur* be working here as *might*? Is it working as an adverb or a particle?

Answer (score 4):

It is used as a modal particle here. Its meaning as described in DWDS:

General meaning as a modal particle:

> dient meist der **Verstärkung** und oft der Satzbelebung; ohne eigentliche Bedeutung

In interrogative sentences:

> in Fragesätzen, umgangssprachlich, drückt innere Anteilnahme,
>   **Beunruhigung**, Verwunderung, Unwillen aus

Even though in your case this is not a real interrogative sentence, but the meaning is the same as if it was used in an interrogative sentence. So, mother and grandmother are **really worried**, *beunruhigt*.

So it's basically an emphasizing word. Links:

1. https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nur_denn_doch
2. https://www.dwds.de/wb/nur (under II)